# How do I add an array instead of objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

In MongoDB,

I know how to insert objects, such as:

```
db.animals.insert(
    {"name": "cat"},
    {"name" : "dog"},
    {"name" : "zebra"}
)
```

But how do I insert an array instead? So I don't have to define a key/value pair? Such as:

```
db.animals.insert([
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "zebra"
])
```

This last one doesn't work.

The reason why I want to insert an array, is that I want to get the following data when I do a `db.animals.find({})`

```
"cat", "dog", "zebra"
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, as the smallest unit of MongoDB is the document, and as you may guess an array is not a document. As an alternative, you could go this way.

```
db.animals.insert({
    animals: [
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "zebra"
    ]
)
```

And then you will have:

```
> db.animals.find({})
{_id: <somethig>, animals: ["cat", "dog", "zebra"]}
```